# Saving Custom Field Values to User Profile

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, usermodel

I have a custom user field 'myuserfield'

How do I save a value to this field via a plugin in Craft3?

Here is my current attempt.

```
    $myvar = '12345';
    Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->setFieldValue('myuserfield', $myvar);
    $myid = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->getFieldValue('myuserfield');
```

When I echo $myid it does, in fact, give me the new value ($myvar or 12345) but when I check the control panel the value is not saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used August's answer, but fixed it:

Put this at the top:

```
use craft\elements\User;
```

Then the updating code

```
$myUser = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity();
$myUser->setFieldValue('fieldHand', 'value');

Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($myUser, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure and stash a reference to the User element you want to edit:

```
$myUser = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity();
$myUser->setFieldValue('myUserField', 'New Field Value');

if (Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($myUser)) {
    echo "User saved.";
}
```

Otherwise, you may end up repeatedly fetching the stale record out of the database, instead of saving the modified instance.

> Note: The similarly-named `Craft::$app->getUsers()` is a method for getting the Users Service instance, which is responsible for saving users. Not to be confused with `Craft::$app->getUser()`, which is a (Yii) method for fetching the current user (the subsequent call to `getIdentity()` retrieves the Craft Element for the user).

Comment: I get this error now - Calling unknown method: craft\services\Users::saveUser()

Comment: @DavidAaronMcInnis Sorry! Updated the answer—took a bad guess at the method, but it turns out you save Users just like any other Element, via the Elements service.